# regexp for renaming multiple files using 'rename.pl'

Tags: regex, linux, perl, rename

I'm using [rename.pl](http://stackoverflow.org/wiki/Rename.pl) to rename a multiple files. I am having trouble coming up with the right regexp. My file names are of the form:

nn.some.title.string.ext

I want to change just the first '.' to ' - '. I thought this would work but it does not.

```
s/\.?/ - /
```

Can someone help me out with this? TIA.

Comment: Why did you use `?` quantifier? It makes the pattern optional. Remove it. `s/\./ - /` should work.

Comment: Are you renaming mp3 files? :)

Comment: `s/([^\.]*)\./$1-/` Just try this

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is my understanding that regexp is greedy and will use all '.' not just the first one. I thought by adding the '?' it will limit it to the first one. So the question is how do I stop after the first match?

Comment: Doesn't `s/\./ - /`  work as expected?

Comment: ssr1012: Thanks. That did it. I didn't realize I could set a variable ($1) with regex.

Comment: @WtRiker: Why do you need the group and the backreference at all? If you do not use `/g` modifier, you will only find *one single* match in the input.

Comment: Please ***don't use*** that program. It is amateurish code, and uses `eval` inappropriately and unnecessarily.

Comment: @ssr1012: That is pretty poor code too. It is overkill when `s/\./-/` will do just fine

Comment: @Borodin: Ummm. I know and given that two regex an option.

Answer (score 2):

`\.?` can match a sequence of zero characters, so `s/\.?/ - /` replaces the dot or the empty string at the start of the input.

```
"abc.def.ghi" ⇒  " - abc.def.ghi"
".abc"        ⇒  " - abc"
```

---

To replace the first `.`, you can use the following:

```
s/\./ - /
```

```
"abc.def.ghi" ⇒ "abc - def.ghi"
```

---

To substitute all `.` but a leading one or the one in the extension, you can use the following:

```
s/(?!^)\.(?!\w+\z)/ - /g
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you will want to make sure that firs point is not the last. I mean if by any chance you will have nn_some_title_string.ext file name the script will not change a last dot.

```
$fileName = "nn.some.title.string.ext";

$fileName =~s/\.(?=\w+\.\w+)/-/;

print "FileName: " . $fileName ."\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

Just try this for simple regex pattern.

```
my $str = "nn.some.title.string.ext";

$str=~s/^([^\.]*)\./$1-/i;
or
$str=~s/\./-/;

#^([^\.]*)       Starting point upto the first dot

print $str;
```

Comment: I guess you need the `/i` modifier in case you come across lower-case full stops?

Comment: hahaha... Just I copied the regex from the previous line. Thanks.